# How to get particular text from the link by reverse search using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
wo_no = "54789"
href = "https://huio.pavilion.co/3/072144b5-f1a0-4dd4-9bb6-d5b7f96b144d/54789"
guid_search = re.search("/(.*)/"+str(wo_no),str(href))
print(guid_search)
```

Required_solution: 072144b5-f1a0-4dd4-9bb6-d5b7f96b144d

Is there any solution to search text before wo_no and between "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

wo_no = "54789"
href = "https://huio.pavilion.co/3/072144b5-f1a0-4dd4-9bb6-d5b7f96b144d/54789"
pattern = rf"/([^/]+)/{wo_no}"
guid_search = re.search(pattern, href)

if guid_search:
    required_solution = guid_search.group(1)
    print(required_solution)
else:
    print("Pattern not found.")
```

In this code, I've used a regular expression pattern r"/([^/]+)/" + str(wo_no) which consists of the following parts:

- "/([^/]+)/": This part of the pattern captures a sequence of
  characters between two slashes / and stores it as a group. The
  ([^/]+) part is a capturing group that matches any character except a
  slash one or more times.
- str(wo_no): This is the literal value of wo_no (in this case,
  "54789") converted to a string.

The re.search function is then used to search for this pattern within the href string. If a match is found, the .group(1) method retrieves the text captured by the capturing group, which is the desired solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

href = "https://huio.pavilion.co/3/072144b5-f1a0-4dd4-9bb6-d5b7f96b144d/54789"
wo_no = "54789"

# Constructing a regex pattern to find the ID between slashes
pattern = r"/([^/]+)/{0}".format(wo_no)

# Using re.search to find the pattern in the href string
match = re.search(pattern, href)

if match:
    extracted_id = match.group(1)
    print(extracted_id)
else:
    print("ID not found")
```